# Take records from set and count how many records for each player id

Tags: java, sorting, set, leaderboard

I'm making a leaderboard in my game and I have tiles with certain player ids assigned to them.

I need to take the following data (which is a set containing my 'Tile' records):

```
    [Tile[id=eeebeaa4e03c8910e5c17925439f1fa1abb,position=Vec[x=-11.0, y=6.0, z=73.0], player_id=1oyr8l], Tile[id=3c10969e83a61f44139d5dbeb8b41c9e,position=Vec[x=-12.0, y=6.0, z=73.0], player_id=1oyr8l], Tile[id=f51fd6f3eb407305a49bde1cb2cf44fe,position=Vec[x=-12.0, y=6.0, z=74.0], player_id=qX9Bh7]]
```

I want to format it into something like:

```
    1oyr8l: 2
    qX9Bh7: 1
```

Or in code form:

```
    public record Tile(String id, Vec position, String owner) {
    // irrelevant code here
    }

    private final Set<Tile> userTiles = getTiles() // dummy func but you get the idea
```

I want to take `userTiles`, which is a `Set<Tile>` and make it into the sorted & counted format I showed above in text format, but in the form of a `HashMap`, such as:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> leaderboard = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Comment: What is this data structure? Is it just a string that you need to process, or have you provided a representation of some other structure?

Comment: @codebod I updated it to include code examples if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your Tiles. `for(Tile t : getTiles())`

Extract the player ID. `String playerId = t.player_id()`

Check if the player ID exists in the HashMap. `if leaderboard.containsKey(playerId)`

If it does, increment the value for that key.

If not, add the map with a value of 1.